# syntax error i've never seen before

Tags: python, syntax

i'm writing a phylogenetic tree program in python and i'm running into a small problem i've not encountered before, i have looked into it and nothing quite describes the problem i have, i get a syntax error from this code:

```
 for x in range(len(matrix)):
            # Print the label
            print(seq0[x-1], end == ' ') if x > 0 else print( ' ', end == '')
```

the error says:

```
 File "/home/brandon/OptimalAlignmentSensitive.py", line 206
print(seq0[x-1], end == ' ') if x > 0 else print( ' ', end == '')
```

and it points to the 't' in the second print statement. has anyone else had this problem? i don't understand what to do i have tried adding spaces and such but nothing helps.

Comment: Abusing the ternary expression like that is a bad idea, use a normal `if` statement. Looping by index is also a really bad idea.

Comment: does `seq0[x-1]` always exists? (also when `x = 0` and `x-1 = -1`)

Comment: @TVproductions Look at the test being performed, that code will only execute if `x > 0`.

Comment: It looks to me like your if statement isn't formatted properly.  Try: http://pych.atomidata.com/code

Comment: @Lattyware Is my Python that bad ;-) ? I tought that the `x > 0` check is after the print statement.

Comment: @Lawson They are abusing the ternary operator, it's not an `if` statement.

Comment: @TVproductions The ternary operator checks the condition, if it's true, evaluates and returns the left hand side, otherwise returns the right hand side. Using it for side effects is a terribly bad idea, however.

Comment: People like to generalize a lot. Looping over indices is not bad depending on the context, usually if you don't have a particular data structure to iterate over available but depending on the length of another data structure. Whether or not that applies here, however, I can't say. The difference between "using" and "abusing" is also skewed by perception at times...

Comment: @Lattyware Conclusion: My Python is that bad ;-). Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: This is valid in Python 3 by the way, invalid in Python 2. I assume that code checker only works for Python 2 code, as it flagged that an error. That's because in Python 3, `print` is a function.

Comment: @StjepanBakrac I completely disagree - unless your problem is actually reliant upon the indices (which is *extremely* rare), there are better ways to do it in Python. I haven't seen a case where looping by index is a better option. It's worse for readability and flexibility.

Comment: Is this exactly `Syntax Error`?

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `from __future__ import print_function`, and writing `print(' ', end='')` with a single '=' in the `print` function.

Comment: What's the problem of `end == ''`? Maybe `Name Error` if `end` is not defined there, but why `Syntax Error`?

Comment: @MostafaR Because named arguments are given with a single `=`. That's the syntax of the language, hence the error. `end` doesn't need to be defined here, it's a parameter name, not a variable.

Comment: @Lattyware OK, but if you write it with `==` it will be a conditional statement, so it should be `False` or `True` if `end` is defined, otherwise it will cause a `NameError: name 'end' is not defined`.

Comment: @MostafaR You are entirely correct. He must be running 2.x, and hence getting the error as `print` is a statement - while the ternary operator only accepts expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is the use of the ternary operator. You are using 2.x, where `print` is a statement - while the ternary operator only accepts expressions. Replace it with an `if` statement:

```
 for x in xrange(len(matrix)):
     if x > 0:
         print(seq0[x-1], end == ' ')
     else:
         print(' ', end == '')
```

This probably won't do what you want though. This will print a `tuple`, while you probably wanted to use the keyword argument from 3.x's `print()` function. This doesn't exist in 2.x, and instead, that functionality is produced by leaving a trailing comma (without brackets to construct a tuple).

```
 for x in range(len(matrix)):
     if x > 0:
         print seq0[x-1], 
     else:
         print " ",
```

In general, using the ternary operator to emulate a single line `if` statement is a bad practice anyway, even where it does work. As stated in my comments, iteration by index is generally a bad idea, and can probably be removed, but that would require more insight into the operation at hand.